# Is there a way to access value of nested json and add it outside the the nested Object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Sorry I couldn't think of better words to phrase my question.

So the issue is say I have a nested json and for some reason I want to fetch the value of a nested key value pair Object and place it outside.

Json I have

```
DataSource=  [
      {
        "a": 1,
        "name": "jack",
        "version": 1,
        "Id": "39da",
        "active": false,
        "userId": "jack_user",
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": 7080,
            "key": "country",
            "value": "in",
          },
    {
            "id": 7081,
            "key": "state",
            "value": "xyz",
          },
    ]}]
```

Json I want :

```
 DataSource=  [
      {
        "a": 1,
        "name": "jack",
        "version": 1,
        "Id": "39da",
        "active": false,
        "userId": "jack_user",
    "country": "in"
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": 7080,
            "key": "country",
            "value": "in",
          },
    {
            "id": 7081,
            "key": "state",
            "value": "xyz",
          },
    ]}]
```

Using the below Code I am able to Iterate over whole JSON.However I am unable to pick an Object from Properties Array.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < this.DataSource.length; i++) {
          var tempDataSource = this.DataSource;
          console.log(tempDataSource );
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Also why just `"country": "in"` and not also `"state": "xyz"`?

Comment: I am able to iterate on Json and fetch whatever value I want but I don't know how to show that value outside. There are multiple values I want only based on condition.Basically I want to filter if key == 'country' then only show it outside

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.
Here I am assuming data array has only one object.

```
const data = [
  {
    "a": 1,
    "name": "jack",
    "version": 1,
    "Id": "39da",
    "active": false,
    "userId": "jack_user",
    "properties": [
      {
        "id": 7080,
        "key": "country",
        "value": "in",
      },
      {
        "id": 7081,
        "key": "state",
        "value": "xyz",
      },
    ]
  }
]

data[0].properties.forEach(obj => {
  if (data[0][obj.key] == 'country') {
    data[0][obj.key] = obj.value
  }
})

console.log(data)
```

output -

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "name": "jack",
    "version": 1,
    "Id": "39da",
    "active": false,
    "userId": "jack_user",
    "properties": [
      {
        "id": 7080,
        "key": "country",
        "value": "in"
      },
      {
        "id": 7081,
        "key": "state",
        "value": "xyz"
      }
    ],
    "country": "in"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try my snippet below

```js
let obj = [{
  "a": 1,
  "name": "jack",
  "version": 1,
  "Id": "39da",
  "active": false,
  "userId": "jack_user",
  "properties": [{
      "id": 7080,
      "key": "country",
      "value": "in",
    },
    {
      "id": 7081,
      "key": "state",
      "value": "xyz",
    },
  ]
}];

console.log('berfore', obj);

obj[0][obj[0].properties[0].key] = obj[0].properties[0].value;

console.log('after', obj);
```